# How to change zip file from using Internet Explorer as default opening program back to original zip file

Tags: windows-vista, zip

I recently had ROMs for a Gameboy Advance emulator that were zip files, and I accidentally changed them to Internet Explorer files. Now, I can't figure out how to change them back to zip files. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Open an explorer window to the directory where you have a .zip file.  Right-click and select "Open with ...".  Choose WinZip, check "Always use the selected program..." and then click OK.

Answer (score 1):

To find these settings go to Start>Default Programs. There you can set default programs and associate file types (you highlight the extension and choose which program opens that type).

[Microsoft Link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Change-which-programs-Windows-uses-by-default)